# Fatal error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent in

Tags: php

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->config("master");
    $this->oops();
    $this->database();
    $this->load->config("lang");
    $this->load->model("functions");
}
```

what is wrong with the code? i have no idea whats wrong!
Can anyone help me pls?

Sorry for my english, i come from germany!

Comment: your class does not inherit (using `extends` keyword) from any parent class.

Comment: i have no idea to fix it :(

Comment: do you wish to access the construct of the parent class? perhaps try in class definition class child extends parent

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EDRb92Km here is the full file

Comment: your class migration does not extends to some other class.

Answer (score 13):

`parent::` is for accessing the parent classes implementation of a method. Your class doesn't have a parent, because it does not `extend` any class. Hence the error.

```
class Foo {

    public function bar() {
        echo 'bar';
    }

}

class Baz extends Foo {

    public function bar() {
        parent::bar();
        echo 'baz';
    }

}
```

Here `parent` makes sense, because there is a parent class.

```
class Foo {

    public function bar() {
        parent::bar();
    }

}
```

Here `parent` makes no sense, because there is no parent, hence error. Since it doesn't make sense and serves no purpose, just remove it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206274/discussion-on-answer-by-deceze-fatal-error-cannot-access-parent-when-current).

Comment: Correct answer. Somehow, this error only showed up after updating from PHP 7.3 to 7.4.

Answer (score 4):

You need to extend a parent class to be able to use its' constructor.

```
class migration extends PARENTCLASS {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        .......
    }
```

Comment: here all 3 files:

http://pastebin.com/TUUUwFbm

http://pastebin.com/sxYcns2W
 
http://pastebin.com/EDRb92Km

i have no idea

Comment: @slyceR refer to deceze's answer. If you're trying to extend that model, just add that in.

Comment: sorry i dont understand that im totally php noob

Comment: Are you trying to do the same as the first 2 files?

Comment: i become this module, its doesnt work for me. its works normally

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who has come across this error even though you are not intending to inherit from a parent, or if you do inherit properly from a parent, it is entirely possible to get this error as a result of an erroneous cut-n-paste fragment.

eg. If you cut and pasted some __construct() code and inadvertently included the code within it, then you will get this error. Take note of whether the class is being extended and then delete the erroneous code if not.

```
class Subscription /* this class not intended to be extended */
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();/* <--- erroneous paste code  */
        $this->states         = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->clusters       = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Even though you may have an appropriate use of parent::__construct(), it may have been erroneously pasted in another class you are not looking at (not so obvious).

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon, I hope to help with my solution. I had the same problem, my solution was to replace in the files where it was showing the parent error by $this->jsonSerialize()

```php
public function jsonSerialize(){
        if (get_parent_class() == ""){
            return $values;
        }
        else{
            return array_merge(parent::jsonSerialize(), $values);
        }
    }
```

this was the change

```php
public function jsonSerialize(){
        if (get_parent_class() == ""){
            return $values;
        }
        else{
            return array_merge($this->jsonSerialize(), $values);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are facing this issue in wordpress, the simplest & easiest fix is:

Remove

```
parent::$_type
```

Change to

```
$this
```

in the error page / line